# Is this how female and male gametes look like in plants?

Tags: genetics, meiosis, allele

In the red box, the pink one is female sex cell I presume and the blue one is a male sex cell.

http://prntscr.com/dsii2x Am I right? or are these chromosomes.. I'm confused.

This is law of segregation.

Comment: Gametes don't look like that. It is a simplified colourful diagram to explain Meiosis. Cells and cell components are not coloured in nature unless they have pigments in them (e.g. Nostoc sp. doesn't need staining it appears green under microscopel).

Comment: Then what is that though? And how do gametes look like?

Comment: The blue and red colours are to distinguish between the maternal and paternal chromosomes as you have thought. I don't find any other possible reason for colouring them differently.

Comment: I just have one more question though.. If these these two are diploid cells, and both of them separate then how is gametes related to this at all? is it because gametes are needed for this to occur in the first place (the occurring diploid cells?)

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: @OkamaKsakas Please note that with the icon that looks like a landscape, you can insert an image directly in the post and not just a link to an image stored somewhere on a different site. It makes the post much more pleasant to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are very unclear and your interpretation of the figure seems very wrong (no offense). You should have a look at an intro course (such as [this one by Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/classical-genetics)) as asking such intro questions here will require for one to rewrite an entire course.

The pink and blue thingies on the image are chromosomes, not gametes. A gamete is a haploid cell (we can see 4 of them at the bottom of the figure). One chromosome (say the pink one) has been inherited by the mother of the individual and the other chromosome (say the blue one) has been inherited by the father of the individual.

Let's assume that the segregation we see on the figure happens in a female individual. So, on the figure we see female diploid cells and female haploid cells. The female haploid cells are called ovules (there is a bit of oversimplification here). You can imagine the same process of segregation could occur in a male individual. The male haploid cells are called spermatozoid (there is a bit of oversimplification here). The male and female gametes might fuse to become a zygote which will develop in a new fully grown individual. The colors of the chromosomes in this scenario indicate whether the chromosome originally come from the grandmother or the grandmother of the zygote.

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you in PM?

Comment: @OkamaKsakas You can find my contact information via my website which you'll find via my profile. Just click on my name and select the tab profile.

Comment: I'm not sure how to send you a message via twitter, unfortunately. I sent you a tweet though

Comment: Just send an email then. All the info is on [my website](http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~matthey/contact.html).